# handling multiple users in a flask application

Tags: flask, multiprocessing, uwsgi

I have an simple login-based application that serves different pages to different users. Problem im facing here is when two users are logging in at once from two different systems. if user A comes in and B loggs in then when A refreshes his/her page user A can see What user B can see. does flask app not handle two processes at a time?
or should i just use another server on this for the support.
or is there a way i can implement threading for this purpose.

i found uwsgi but i have no idea about it but can it serve my purpose in any way?

Please help me on this i have been working on this for a month now and i could not find a legit answer for this one.

Comment: How are you handling this login? You should be using sessions – https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions

Comment: [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has already solved this for you.

Comment: while a user logs in im storing their user name on a session but i am using this user name to query from db the page access he/she has. again this session variable is getting overwritten and thats y the frst user is seeing wat the second is having access for

Comment: does flask-login work with multiple users logging in i tried implemeting this but i was struck so i gave up on that.

Comment: i dont think flask-login is of much use for me as i hae manually written code for logging in and logout of user and @login_required part. i need to handle the functionality of restricting pages for both users logged in at once

Answer (score 0):

Use **sessions** , have **strong app secret key** and have a database such as **SQLAlchemy**

Comment: Thank You! although sessions were not exactly satisfying my scenario a combination of sessions and cookies worked.